# Android Asynctask deprecated

Tags: android-asynctask

Since android's Asynctask class is deprecated, what are the new ways to implement the same task? I was trying to parse JSON data using the async task, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use

Java Executor

LoaderManager

Retrofit or volley to handle this request easily

or in Kotlin you can use coroutines